# Heroku Facebook App - redirect user when they deny permission

Tags: facebook, heroku

Sorry for my English.

I would like to host my application on facebook heroku.

I followed [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook), and managed to create an application.

But how do I add a redirect to login and application permissions? I.e. when the user accesses the URL `still-bayou-6120.herokuapp.com` or `apps.facebook.com/still-bayou-6120`
he is redirected to the login screen, and then he "accepts" or "denies" permissions from the user?

In the tutorial above they do not explain how to

> redirect user when they deny permission

I searched on google but did not find any article.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In "index.erb", there is a Facebook init() function.

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : "<%= @app['id'] %>",                     // App ID
      channelUrl : "<%= url_no_scheme('/channel.html') %>", // Channel File
      status     : true,                                    // check login status
      cookie     : true,                                    // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true                                     // parse XFBML
    });
    // Listen to the auth.login which will be called when the user logs in
    // using the Login button
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      // We want to reload the page now so Ruby can read the cookie that the
      // Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
      // window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
      // post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
      // user asking if they want to send data again.
      window.location = window.location;
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
};
```

So, you can add some code to check if user deny permission or not as following.

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : "<%= @app['id'] %>",                     // App ID
      channelUrl : "<%= url_no_scheme('/channel.html') %>", // Channel File
      status     : true,                                    // check login status
      cookie     : true,                                    // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true                                     // parse XFBML
    });

    //Check Status
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location = window.location;
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
      } else {
        //Deny permission//
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
      }
    });
};
```

PS. I don't run this code yet. Also, please check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) for Facebook Login.